# Counting numbers in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Say I have the following long line selected in Emacs. How can I cound how many numbers (or NaN) I have?

I tried `M-x count-words` but it yields the wrong number. It says `1 line 1135 words and 3565 characters`, but it actually has `640` numbers

> 0.967 1.043 1.313 1.598 1.879 2.151 2.421 2.918 3.209 3.478 3.736 3.975 0.917 1.012 1.317 1.607 1.900 2.173 2.437 2.929 3.203 3.473 3.714 3.954 1.081 1.297 1.570 1.753 1.964 2.209 2.456 2.699 2.947 3.196 3.566 3.822 4.050 4.268 4.423 0.950 1.080 1.212 1.343 1.617 1.911 2.219 2.487 2.750 3.213 3.489 3.732 3.957 4.180 0.965 1.074 1.176 1.280 1.381 1.636 1.871 2.108 2.357 2.614 3.080 3.374 3.666 3.943 4.205 0.992 1.151 1.294 1.422 1.527 1.653 1.894 2.094 2.311 2.557 2.820 3.263 3.559 3.849 4.115 4.349 0.895 0.997 1.119 1.215 1.313 1.401 1.649 1.898 2.152 2.411 2.667 3.143 3.446 3.723 3.969 4.207 0.947 1.155 1.369 1.599 1.838 2.094 2.597 2.941 3.265 3.570 3.852 1.120 1.396 1.680 1.970 2.297 2.781 3.075 3.344 3.596 3.835 1.020 1.181 1.335 1.514 1.675 1.868 2.124 2.401 2.719 2.995 3.255 3.617 3.896 4.131 4.309 4.461 0.893 1.003 1.094 1.202 1.464 1.732 2.022 2.289 2.562 3.030 3.338 3.609 3.852 4.095 1.026 1.219 1.403 1.585 1.759 2.041 2.285 2.535 2.796 3.058 3.486 3.754 4.009 4.210 4.394 0.900 1.005 1.127 1.255 1.415 1.715 2.015 2.322 2.622 2.924 3.346 3.624 3.842 4.034 4.212 0.926 1.045 1.143 1.392 1.648 1.905 2.155 2.423 2.912 3.227 3.509 3.767 4.017 0.968 1.154 1.335 1.511 1.655 1.813 1.968 2.188 2.428 2.659 2.932 3.204 3.591 3.878 4.122 4.334 4.506 1.027 1.194 1.315 1.433 1.536 1.699 1.826 2.063 2.352 2.653 2.960 3.187 3.575 3.842 4.058 4.247 4.427 0.963 1.147 1.351 1.539 1.679 1.883 2.070 2.279 2.551 2.828 3.234 3.564 3.886 4.150 4.315 0.966 1.141 1.294 1.446 1.596 1.857 2.156 2.413 2.669 2.879 3.307 3.592 3.828 4.064 4.300 0.924 1.163 1.428 1.712 1.992 2.291 2.778 3.103 3.397 3.659 3.893 0.896 1.008 1.109 1.196 1.296 1.532 1.781 2.038 2.301 2.574 3.059 3.354 3.630 3.893 4.144 0.930 1.063 1.330 1.580 1.865 2.160 2.439 2.912 3.221 3.520 3.784 3.988 0.954 1.079 1.205 1.282 1.465 1.676 1.908 2.160 2.411 2.881 3.246 3.554 3.831 4.081 0.905 0.972 1.040 1.287 1.541 1.802 2.080 2.384 2.876 3.183 3.471 3.730 3.969 1.045 1.235 1.398 1.583 1.758 2.048 2.294 2.522 2.763 3.009 3.417 3.689 3.941 4.184 4.411 0.964 1.075 1.186 1.291 1.525 1.782 2.063 2.347 2.606 3.079 3.394 3.661 3.899 4.131 0.957 1.118 1.276 1.404 1.611 1.848 2.118 2.406 2.680 3.129 3.465 3.764 3.997 4.192 0.982 1.114 1.263 1.527 1.800 2.084 2.382 2.680 3.137 3.429 3.688 3.917 4.127 0.982 1.054 1.133 1.189 1.243 1.327 1.568 1.822 2.075 2.351 2.629 3.086 3.386 3.667 3.922 4.153 0.965 1.098 1.238 1.399 1.503 1.591 1.670 1.895 2.128 2.371 2.622 2.886 3.341 3.634 3.897 4.126 4.338 0.915 1.050 1.183 1.300 1.443 1.558 1.825 2.069 2.348 2.641 2.916 3.360 3.634 3.893 4.109 4.308 1.025 1.187 1.363 1.512 1.657 1.806 2.085 2.346 2.595 2.846 3.091 3.500 3.755 3.999 4.232 4.454 1.065 1.231 1.400 1.560 1.717 1.870 1.984 2.198 2.427 2.655 2.896 3.110 3.524 3.813 4.060 4.287 4.501 0.895 0.991 1.089 1.183 1.302 1.409 1.666 1.926 2.168 2.434 2.700 3.148 3.438 3.718 3.988 4.230 1.027 1.169 1.348 1.439 1.581 1.788 1.992 2.272 2.564 2.977 3.327 3.601 3.871 4.052 4.181 4.181 4.181 6235366411468800.000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My unsophisticated approach to this problem is to use `count-matches` to count the record separators, then add one.  Assuming your separator is a space, select the line and enter `M-x count-matches <RET><space><RET>`.  Instead of counting delimiters, supplying the following regex to `count-matches` works with your data, but is more tedious to type: `\b-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b\|\bNaN\b`.  Your example data does not show any negative data, but I included the optional '-' in the regex in case it could.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `count-matches` with `\.` as the regexp.